# Logo and picture on titlepage

Tags: graphics, titles

I need to make a title page with a logo on the top left corner, the title and the author centered and another picture under this. I tried this code but the problem is that the second image is right under the logo and the title and the author are on another page.

```
%%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\geometry{dvips,a4paper,margin=1.5in}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}{`convert #1 `dirname #1`/`basename #1 .tif`.png}



\begin{document}

    \begin{titlepage}

        \includegraphics[width = 40mm]{logo.jpg}

        \begin{center}

            \title{Report}
            \author{Author}
            \date{Septembre 2013}

            \includegraphics[width = 40mm]{image.png}

        \end{center}

    \end{titlepage}

    \maketitle

\newpage

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\vspace{2.5cm}

\section{Abstract}

\newpage

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\maketitle` has a predefined layout. To change it you should edit that command. In your case, is better to type the title page as you want. Instead of using `\title{}` format it using `\textbf{}`, `large` or something else. Also, you can use `\vspace{??cm}` to insert vertical space.

Comment: My images have the same width and height, about 200x200 px

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that `\author`, `\title` and `\date`  are only definitions, not commands to print this information.  These commands in `titlepage` without `\maketitle` do nothing. So all is printed when you said `\maketitle`, that is, after the title page.

Usually you choose between using only `\maketitle` at the beginning of the document, that print  `\author`, `\title` and `\date`  at the top of the article (defined before, preferably in the preamble) with a default format, or a `titlepage` environment to have a title page, where you simply insert  what you want with the format that you want.

But in order to clean the `document` environment, you can also redefine `\maketitle` so this command followed by a `\newpage` (or  inside `titlepage`) make all the work:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass[a4paper12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\title{Report}
\author{Author}
\date{Septembre 2013}

% Definition of \maketitle
\makeatletter         
\def\@maketitle{
\raggedright
\includegraphics[width = 40mm]{logo.jpg}\\[8ex]
\begin{center}
{\Huge \bfseries \sffamily \@title }\\[4ex] 
{\Large  \@author}\\[4ex] 
\@date\\[8ex]
\includegraphics[width = 40mm]{image.png}
\end{center}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\maketitle
% \thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage

\tableofcontents

\newpage
\vspace{2.5cm}
\section{Abstract}
\newpage
\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why doesn't with work with `amsbook` instead of `article` ? (It gives an `There's no line here to end` error at the `\maketitle` line.)

Answer (score 5):

[Fran](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/11604/fran)'s solution works, but I prefer the following variant, because it essentially allows you to prepend the title page before the original document, which is sometimes useful.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{My Title}
\author{My name}
\date{November 2, 2015}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
    \begin{titlepage}
        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{logo.png}\\[4ex]
            {\huge \bfseries  \@title }\\[2ex] 
            {\LARGE  \@author}\\[50ex] 
            {\large \@date}
        \end{center}
    \end{titlepage}
\makeatother
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage

%Add content for page two here (useful for two-sided printing)
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage

\maketitle
\setcounter{page}{1} %Start the actually document on page 1

\begin{abstract}
...
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, I like this, but both with your solution and with Fran's, it claims not to be able to find the author.  Here is the code

Answer (score 3):

Another elegant solution would be to use the [PGF/TikZ](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/) package and place the [TikZ](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/) command after the standard `\maketitle` call, e.g.

```
\tikz [remember picture, overlay] %
\node [shift={(1cm,-1cm)}] at (current page.north west) %
[anchor=north west] %
{\includegraphics{logo}};
```

Option `current page.north west` ensures the logo will be at the top left corner of the title page and the `shift` option `[shift={(1cm,-1cm)}]` allows to control the offsets from the top left.

Comment: I tried it with report document, however, the logo is placed in the second page, not the title page.

Comment: Try to reset the title page formatting by placing `\thispagestyle{empty}` command right after the TikZ commands for logo.

Comment: `tikz` is so powerful and produces beautiful stuff. Like `vim`, once you get comfortable with it, everything else looks subpar.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much.  I tried both Fran's and user2768's solutions and in both cases it claims not to be able to find the author.  The problem lies in the use of the \documentclass{amsart} rather than \documentclass{article}.  Is there any way around this?

Here is the code

\documentclass [a4paper, 12pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{Standard Operating Procedures}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{logo_OSP.png}\[4ex
{\huge \bfseries  @title }\[2ex]
{\LARGE  @author}\[50ex]
{\large @date}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\makeatother
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage

\end{document}

and here is the error

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./front page.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsart.cls
Document Class: amsart 2020/05/29 v2.20.6
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/epsfig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psfrag/psfrag.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./front page.aux)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))

LaTeX Warning: No \author given.

./front page.tex:18: LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
...

l.18             {\LARGE  @author}\
[50ex]
?
[0
Non-PDF special ignored!
 header=psfrag.pro
{/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map} <./logo_
OSP.png>] (./front page.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/p
ublic/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/pu
blic/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb>
Output written on "front page.pdf" (1 page, 89386 bytes).
SyncTeX written on "front page.synctex.gz"
Transcript written on "front page.log".

Comment: How does this answer the question?