# Image and coauthor (sbtitle) in the very first page [BOOK class]

Tags: positioning

I'm sorry if you can find my questions very stupid, but I need some help.
I'm actually writing my thesis and I've encountered a couple of problems.

First of all, I notice, I'm using the class book and I don't want to change class, because I've recently lost a lot of time in positioning images in the whole document. I know this isn't the best choice, but "c'est la vie".

I need to put an image in the very first page of the thesis with my uni's logo and I need to write the names of my Relator and Correlator too.

I'm actually using this code:

```
\title{A support vector classifier based on Gaussian random processes for region-based remote sensing images}
\author{Gabriele.S.}
\date{}
\maketitle
```

but there's no way to insert a sort of "\subtitle{}" or "\coauthor" code.
Do you know any solutions? Thanks for all.

Comment: Hi and welcome, i fear you have to design your own titlepage. This is not as hard as it might sound. Please have a look at [customizing my titlepage](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210280/37907) for some first hints and ideas.

Comment: You can have a lok at [Logo and picture on titlepage](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/125552)  and [How to insert an image in the front cover of a report?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13912) as well.