# figure on first page ( titlepage)

Tags: floats, titles

Why isn't it possible to place a picture on the bottom of the first page/titlepage, for example your universities logo? 
It always jumps to the page after or creates a page above it. However also with minipage I was not able to fix this problem,

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: For such a logo you do not want a floating figure so you do not want `\begin{figure}` just use `\includegraphics` that never moves.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Use the `titling` package. It ptrovides 4 hooks to place what you want before title, between title and author or between author and date, and after date.

Comment: this may be useful: [Logo and picture on titlepage](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/125552/579)

Comment: Related: [How to customize my titlepage?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210280)