# How to include figures in the frontpage of the article class

Tags: graphics, article

Apparently, I cannot comment on other people's posts yet. That's why I open this new question, referring to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125552/logo-and-picture-on-titlepage). I am using the code given in Fran's answer. Now, I wonder, how could I include two subtitles to the title? And then center the title in the vertical center as well as in the horizontal center of the page?

I would also like to have another figure at the upper right corner. 
So, for some reason, the `\raggedright` command shifts the first figure to the upper left corner. I was trying `\raggedleft` then and included my other figure that I want in the upper right corner. I did this after I included the figure in the upper left corner. But these figures then are not on the same height.

Comment: graphics are positioned by exactly the same logic a letters, use `\includegraphics{...}\hfill\includegraphics{...}` to put two on the same line.

Comment: Even if all the problems might be solved with a few changes of a previous MWE, try to ask for  only a problem each time. This way it could have more value to others searching solutions for the same concrete problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solve all the problems?

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[a4paper12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{The main title}
\author{The Author}
\def\SubtitleA{One nice subtitle}
\def\SubtitleB{Yet another more subtible}
\date{\today}

\makeatletter         
\def\@maketitle{%
\parindent0pt
\includegraphics[width = 40mm]{example-image-a}\hfill%
\includegraphics[width = 40mm]{example-image-b}
\vfill
\begin{center}\parskip1.500em
{\Huge  \bfseries \sffamily \@title}\par
{\Large  \SubtitleA}\par
{\large  \SubtitleB}\par\bigskip
{\bfseries \sffamily \@author}\par\bigskip 
\@date\par
\vfill
\includegraphics[width = 40mm]{example-image-c}
\end{center}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketitle\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{document}
```

Comment: cool, thx very much Fran!

Comment: for some reason it is not possible to have two authors on the same line, using `\and`.  When I include this `\author{name1 \and name2}` I get the error message `misplaced \crcr` in the line that my `\maketitle` is in

Comment: @user503842 By default each author is placed in a tabular environment,  so that `\and` end the first tabular, add some space and start the new tabular. Solution: change `\@author` by `\begin{tabular}[t]{c}\@author\end{tabular}` (or  alternatively, instead of use tabulars at all, before  redefine maketitle,  change `\and`  to make anything else  (e.g. `\def\and{ and }`, or `\def\and{\qquad}` or `\def\and{...whatever...}`)