# Custom `maketitle` definition in report

Tags: titles, report

Following [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125581) answer I'm trying to customize the cover of a report, which works fine for articles, but doesn't seem to work for reports. For example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\makeatletter         
\def\@maketitle{
\raggedright
\begin{center}
{\Huge \bfseries \sffamily \@title }\\[4ex] 
{\Large  \@author}\\[4ex] 
\@date\\[8ex]
\end{center}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Report}
\author{Author}
\date{Septembre 2013}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

works, but when I change `article` to `report` the custom title page layout is lost. I could manually use e.g. `\begin{titlepage} ..`, but I actually like the idea of having the definition of the title page elsewhere (for example a custom `.sty` file) and only including `title{}`, `author{}`, and `date{}` in each document.

Can this somehow be done using the `report` class?

Comment: It is `a4paper,12pt`, not `a4paper12pt`.

Comment: Sorry, quickly copy-pasted it like this from the example

Comment: No problem, I understand it. See if my answer solves the issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\maketitle` is not a core command; it is defined in each classes. In `article`, it is defined differently from in `report` or `book`.

So why don't you redefine `\maketitle` directly? No need of redefining `\@maketitle`.

Btw to keep the formatting, i.e. apply `\raggedright` for only the title, you need to place the whole thing inside a group.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report} % Not a4paper12pt
\usepackage{geometry}

\makeatletter         
\renewcommand\maketitle{
{\raggedright % Note the extra {
\begin{center}
{\Huge \bfseries \sffamily \@title }\\[4ex] 
{\Large  \@author}\\[4ex] 
\@date\\[8ex]
\end{center}}} % Note the extra }
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\title{Report}
\author{Author}
\date{Septembre 2013}

\maketitle

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]